# Same floating point operation, different results

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754

I really can't wrap my head around the fact that this code gives 2 results for the same formula:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
  // std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
  std::cout.precision(20);
  float a = (exp(M_PI) - M_PI);
  std::cout << (exp(M_PI) - M_PI) << "\n";
  std::cout << a << "\n";
  return (0);
}
```

I don't really think that the IEEE 754 floating point representation is playing a significant role here ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first expression (namely `(exp(M_PI) - M_PI)`) is a `double`, the second expression (namely `a`) is a `float`. Neither even *have* 20 decimal digits of precision, but the `float` has a lot less precision than the `double`.

Comment: time spent with the floating point system and I forgot about the other basic type in C++, great!

Comment: @EricPostpischil what ? Can you explain this ?

Comment: @user2485710: By "first expression" I'm referring to `exp(M_PI) - M_PI`. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

Because `M_PI` are of type `double`, so change `a` to `double`, you will have the same result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
  // std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
  std::cout.precision(20);
  double a = (exp(M_PI) - M_PI);
  std::cout << (exp(M_PI) - M_PI) << "\n";
  std::cout << a << "\n";
  return (0);
}
```